# StepFunction: How to add a date run condition on the parallel state of State Machine

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a state machine which has a bunch of task and parallel states. I have my state machine scheduled to run daily, but I want my parallel state to run only on the 22nd of each month.  On all other days the parallel state should be skipped.

Any idea/suggestion how I can implement this state machine date run condition?

[image]

```json
{
  "StartAt": "Choice State Name?",
  "States": {
    "Choice State Name?": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.StateName",
          "IsPresent": false,
          "Next": "Daily_Job_1"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.StateName",
          "StringEquals": "Daily_Job_1",
          "Next": "Daily_Job_1"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.StateName",
          "StringEquals": "Parallel_Chain",
          "Next": "Parallel_Chain"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.StateName",
          "StringEquals": "Daily_Job_3",
          "Next": "Daily_Job_3"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Job Failed"
    },
    "Job Failed": {
      "Type": "Fail"
    },
    "Daily_Job_1": {
      "Next": "Parallel_Chain",
      "Type": "Task",
      "ResultPath": null,
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:us-west-2:XXXXX:job-definition/dataservices-batch-job-definition-poc:1",
        "JobName": "Daily_Job_1",
        "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:us-west-2:XXXXX:job-queue/getting-started-job-queue-batch-poc",
        "ContainerOverrides": {}
      }
    },
    "Parallel_Chain": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "ResultPath": null,
      "Next": "Daily_Job_3",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Daily_Job_2a",
          "States": {
            "Daily_Job_2a": {
              "Next": "Daily_Job_2b",
              // ... rest like Daily_Job_1
            },
            "Daily_Job_2b": {
              "End": true,
              // ... rest like Daily_Job_1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "Daily_Job_2c",
          "States": {
            "Daily_Job_2c": {
              "Next": "Daily_Job_2d",
              // ... rest like Daily_Job_1
            },
            "Daily_Job_2d": {
              "Next": "Daily_Job_2e",
              // ... rest like Daily_Job_1
            },
            "Daily_Job_2e": {
              "End": true,
              // ... rest like Daily_Job_1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "Daily_Job_3": {
      "End": true,
      // ... rest like Daily_Job_1
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 7200
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Look up the current date before deciding whether to run `ParallelState`

Place a Lambda Task and a Two-Branch Choice State before `ParallelState`.  The Lambda Task outputs a boolean (javascript: `(new Date).getDay() === 22`) to `$.shouldRunParallel`, based on the current date.  A new Choice State after the Lambda continues to the `Parallel_Chain` state if `$.shouldRunParallel` is `true` and skips it if `false`.

1. "Parallel_Chain" and `day === 22`: lambda task, choice task `true` branch, `Parallel_State`, `Daily_Job_3`
2. "Parallel_Chain" and `day !== 22`: lambda task, choice task `false` branch, `Daily_Job_3`
3. "Daily_Job_1" first runs `Daily_Job_1`, next continues as with `Parallel_Chain`
4. "Daily_Job_3" runs `Daily_Job_3`

Comment: Thank you, here instead of calling a lambda i was exploring the Choice Rule and was trying to use context object $$.Execution.StartTime to get time and compare it with the date of 22nd of the month. Here the problem is how to pass dynamic dates for comparison and extract the day of the month.  
I created 2 rules 
Rule #1  (Daily_job_3)
$$.Execution.StartTime >= 2022-01-22T00:00:00Z and $$.Execution.StartTime <= 2022-01-22T23:59:59Z      
Rule #2 (Parallel_state)
$$.Execution.StartTime <= 2022-01-22T00:00:00Z and $$.Execution.StartTime >= 2022-01-22T23:59:59Z
Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Step Functions cannot apply your date comparison logic without Lambda.  Choice comparisons are part of a State Machine's definition, which cannot be changed at execution-time.  To achieve what your comment describes, you would run a Lambda each month to hardcode the new month's date strings in the definition with an [UpdateStateMachine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sfn/classes/updatestatemachinecommand.html) API call.  This approach is perfectly workable, but seems more complex and harder to reason about than a daily run-or-not lambda.